# How to use tokezine/untokenize?

Tags: python, tokenize

I am attempting to rebuild a line of python code after changing some elements using Python's tokenize module. A simple tokenize/untokenize does not rebuild the original code, it adds extra spaces in the output.

Is there a bug in `untokenize` or am I missing something?

```
from tokenize import tokenize, untokenize
from io import BytesIO


def retoken(text):
    result = []
    g = tokenize(BytesIO(text.encode('utf-8')).readline)  # tokenize the string
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _ in g:
        result.append((toknum, tokval))
    return untokenize(result).decode('utf-8')


code = "x.y=12"
print("CODE:", code)
print("RETOKEN:", retoken(code))
```

Output:

```
CODE: x.y=12  
RETOKEN: x .y =12
```

Comment: This is documented behavior for `untokenize`: "The guarantee applies only to the token type and token string as the spacing between tokens (column positions) may change."

Comment: It appears, based on some light experimentation, that `untokenize` adds a space after an identifier token.

Comment: Note that you *can't* rebuild the original line from the tokens alone, because whitespace won't *produce* any tokens for `untokenize` to work with. Most likely, `untokenize` inserts whitespace as a space is both guaranteed to *not* be part of a preceding token and not be treated as a token itself by another call to `tokenize`.

Comment: @chepner can you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it ? The reference for the documentation that I missed is a clean answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `untokenize` states that

> [...] the spacing between tokens (column positions) may change.

I suspect that `untokenize` doesn't examine its entire list of tokens when building its output string. It appears to add a space after an identifier token, as that character is guaranteed to not be part of either the preceding identifier token or whatever token follows it, or to be a token itself. This helps ensure that the `tokenize(untokenize(tokenize(s))) == tokenize(s)`, even though `untokenize(tokenize(s))` may not equal `s`.